# Which texel value is returned during Point sampling of the texture when more than one texels are at the equal distance?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, opengl-es-2.0

Which texel value is returned by the sampler during Point/Nearest neighbor sampling when more than one texels are at the equal distance?

[image: Screen Pixel and texel overlapping]

Eg: In this case (after magnification) where for many pixels (or texture coordinates), 2 texels are at the same distance from its center. Which texel will be returned for the sampling of these pixels.

black dots = center of the pixel
yellow dots = center of the texel

- What is the formula for calculating nearest texel for Nearest-neighbor sampling in OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object):

> If GL_NEAREST is used, then the implementation will select the texel nearest the texture coordinate

So ultimately, the graphics card vendor decides what they consider the nearest texel.

A possible formula multiplies the texture coordinates by the image width / image height and rounds it down to get the texel index.

```
(i, j) = floor(uv * (width, height)),
```

where `*` is component-wise multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, Nico. 
so picking nearest texel will depend on OpenGL API implementation (i.e. sampler in shader or sampler object) or graphics card implementation?

Comment: The OpenGL implementation provided with the driver.

Comment: The OpenGL Wiki is notorious for bad information. Here is a quote from the OpenGL ES spec: `GL_NEAREST: Returns the value of the texture element that is nearest (in Manhattan distance) **to the center of the pixel** being textured.` Source: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml